# Fast in-string search of unique keys in array

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I am working on a program that has to search an array of file names (upwards of 250k to 600k) stored as strings. I have to provide relevant search results based on input, which means in-string searching at least, because I still have to provide relevant results even if the query doesn't match any one of these pre-stored strings exactly.

So far I've tried just a simple `std::vector` and searching it linearly by key name, surprisingly it was fast enough on my computer with about 250k elements, but I was worried that adding in-string checking would slow it waaay down, so I implemented it using `std::unordered_map` and the lookup times were unsurprisingly really fast. But now I have another problem, since the keys are hashed, it's not really possible to in-string search them, and by then you're using the map as a glorified array.

So right know I don't really have a lot of ideas, apart from something vague like storing them in a vector, doing a quick_sort on them, and then binary search, but that still gives me only an exact match. Any ideas?

Comment: you need to implement some kind of indexing. or use existing library/tools.

Comment: You need to provide more details. How long are you keys on average? What is a valid "in-string" match (e.g. any substring of the key must match the query exactly, or matches are fuzzy)? How many queries are expected? So far, it seems like you need to create a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) from all prefixes of your files, and use it to search.

Comment: Seems like a job for a database with full text-indexing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Fuzzy matches are welcome, although exact in-string matches are enough for now. My keys are on avarage 20 characters long. I can provide some code tomorrow if necessary. Right now I just implemented a linear search with a simple std::find, it's enough for about 250k keys but with 1mil keys, it could get slow.

Comment: Note: only the search needs to be fast, the pre-indexing doesn't really matter even if it takes minutes. The goal is to possibly move most of the processing to that stage. It's basically like instant search tools on Windows.